# how to set image instead of Close text in given screenshot?

Tags: android, paint

> I am unable set image instead of **close** text using canvas.**Close**
>   text is created using below method.

```
private void drawCenterText(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    paint.setColor(mToggleMenuTextColor);
    switch (mOrientation) {
    case VERTICAL_RIGHT:
        canvas.drawText(openMenuText,
                getWidth() - paint.measureText(openMenuText),
                getHeight() / 2, paint);

        break;
    case VERTICAL_LEFT:
        canvas.drawText(openMenuText, 2, getHeight() / 2, paint);

        break;
    case HORIZONTAL_TOP:
        canvas.drawText(openMenuText,
                (getWidth() / 2) - (paint.measureText(openMenuText) / 2),
                textSize, paint);

        break;
    case HORIZONTAL_BOTTOM:
        canvas.drawText(openMenuText,
                (getWidth() / 2) - (paint.measureText(openMenuText) / 2),
                getHeight() - (textSize), paint);

        break;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the image is a drawable you can convert it to bitmap and place it instead  of text using canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);. Hope this helps you.

Comment: yes i tried that but images is showing in top left corner.we have to set the margin like this canvas.drawBitmap(icon, 250,950, paint); so we will exactly set it place where close text is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this should help you out, I have not tried it but it should let you get going.

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    int bitWidth = b.getWidth();
    int bitHeight = b.getHeight();

    if (width > 0 && height > 0)
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, (width / 2) - (bitWidth / 2), height - (bitHeight), mPaint);
    else
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, mPaint);
}
```

Where b is my bitmap with any icon initialized as

```
 b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: Thank You. Can you please tell me how can i change the images only selected portion. For Ex, in screenshot, i want to change only gray area images.is it possible if yes then plz tell me

Comment: I guess you will have to set them using the X & Y co-ordinates for the gray part. Try to set image for the gray part so that you can easily replace it using the above method.

Comment: but in which method i can change the images instead of color?

Comment: You can create your own method in view class and call that method from your activity class whenever you require it.